# Google Chrome Content Protection Policy for AngularJS click directives

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, google-chrome, content-security-policy

I have got a very interesting scenario and it would be great to get some insights to the same. Recently I came across a the new Google Chrome's **Content Security Policy** which **does not** allow inline scripts or event hanglers like **onclick or ontouch** within the HTML itself. In short it **makes it mandatory** for us to write those click handlers using javascript in a separate file.

So **instead of** writing something like this:

```
<input id="addRecordBtn" type="button" value="Add record" onclick="addRecord()">
<input id="refreshBtn" type="button" value="Refresh" onclick="refreshList()">
```

I eventually ended up adding jquery event binders using **on** feature of jQuery to something like as shown below:

```
$(document).ready(function(evt){
$('#addRecordBtn').on('click', function(){
    alert("Adding Record");
    AddValueToDB();
});

$('#refreshBtn').on('click', function(){
    alert("Refresh Records");
    ListDBValues();
});

});
```

Now, the above method makes sure the HTML is clean and void of any JavaScript but it also creates a question in my mind how and what would I do if I was using AngularJS or something like the **ng-click** handlers. How to get rid of them?

```
<input id="addRecordBtn" type="button" value="Add record" ng-click="addRecord()">
<input id="refreshBtn" type="button" value="Refresh" ng-click="refreshList()">
```

How would it be possible to **remove ng-click** OR am I wrong in understanding ng-click. Does ng-click **follow** the Chrome's Content Security Policy?

I am getting very limited documentation on this. Few insights would be great.

Thanks,
Ankit.

Comment: This link https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCsp says that "When this mode is on AngularJS will evaluate all expressions up to 30% slower than in non-CSP mode, but no security violations will be raised." So does it mean using the CSP mode will make it slower?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularJS and Content-Security-Policy are documented under the [ngCsp](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCsp) directive.  Here are how the `unsafe` rules affect Angular:

> - `unsafe-eval`: this rule forbids apps to use `eval` or `Function(string)` generated functions (among other things). Angular makes use of this 
>     in the `$parse` service to provide a 30% increase in the speed of 
>     evaluating Angular expressions.
> - `unsafe-inline`: this rule forbids apps from inject custom styles into the document. Angular makes use of this to include some CSS
>     rules    (e.g. `ngCloak` and `ngHide`). To make these directives work when
>     a CSP    rule is blocking inline styles, you must link to the
>     `angular-csp.css` in your HTML manually.

Specifically [ngClick](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) uses an AngularJS expression...

```
<ANY
  ng-click="expression">
...
</ANY>
```

...and an AngularJS [expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) does not need `eval` and works with the `unsafe` rules of Content-Security-Policy.

> Angular does not use JavaScript's `eval()` to evaluate expressions.
>   Instead Angular's `$parse` service processes these expressions.

Comment: I read this as the problem with inline ngclick in Angular is you are putting JavaScript like code into the web page, which is exactly what unsafe-inline for script-src was suppose to stop.

So using Angular is allowing Angular attribute injection, or injection into Angular attributes. When I've understood it all I'll try and solve it.

One approach I've worked with is use Reactjs instead :)

Answer (score 1):

I hope this link should help. 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCsp

Comment: This says that "When this mode is on AngularJS will evaluate all expressions up to 30% slower than in non-CSP mode, but no security violations will be raised." So does it mean using the CSP mode will make it slower?

Comment: 30% slower, yes. But i don't think you will feel it as its just some fraction of seconds